# iPhone UItableview didselectrowAtIndexPath always return the first row selected

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UItableview which have detail view pushed using navigationcontroller.If  i selected a row it shows the details after dismissing the view and selecting another row it is returning the first selected row itself

Comment: Are you sure you didn't implement tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath: as opposed to tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: This one got me, when I get back to the method it really was diddeselect, I never knew there was diddeselect delegate haha, thanks

Comment: @jbat100 thank you so much for pointing out what was so obviously the problem for my code, but I couldn't see it right in front of me.

Answer (score 2):

you should use  below table view delegate method to select the particular cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

try this link you will get more information about tableview

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i have already used this method but still it is returning the first row index

Answer (score 0):

release the old object and recreate a new object of detail view in didSelectRowAtIndexPath because it will use old object every time so viewdidload method will not work...

try this one or post your codes.....